# use Case in Where Clause SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

Hi to make this short.

I need only the column when a condition is met.
if the condition is not met, then I can proceed running my Query without that column as validation.

CONDITION NEEDED.

```
REFERENCE TABLE - TABLE_A
inside TABLE_A there is PARAMETER_NAME AND PARAMETER_VALUE
REQUIRED: PARAMETER_NAME= 'SMS_SEND'
PARAMETER_VALUE = 'TRUE'
```

COLUMN FOR VALIDATION
INSIDE TABLE_B 
INVALID_STAT ---> COLUMN

```
IF PARAMETER_NAME= 'SMS_SEND' and PARAMETER_VALUE = 'TRUE'
THEN I NEED TO CHECK INVALID_STAT IF ITS EQUAL TO 'Y'
ELSE
I DONT NEED TO VALIDATE INVALID_STAT AT ALL



WHERE (CASE
           WHEN 1 = (SELECT DECODE (PARAMETER_VALUE, 'FALSE', 1, 2)
                       FROM TABLE_A
                      WHERE PARAMETER_NAME = 'SMS_SEND')
           THEN
              INVALID_STAT
           ELSE
              'Y'
        END) = 'Y'
```

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` expressions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, no images. And take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex.

Comment: @Zaynul_Abadin_Tuhin I believe that your edit removed part of the original question. If I remember correctly, after the `WHERE` was a `FROM`.

Comment: Can you explain what is actually happening and the rules for content within table_A (please give it a meaningful name - e.g. parameters)? For example, if table A does not have a record with parameter_name = 'SMS_SEND', then the subquery will return no rows. I'm not sure if you are aware of that, but the DECODE won't magically generate a row for you where none exist. Also, is INVALID_STAT a column somewhere or a string literal (i.e must be enclosed in quotes). Please add DDL, sample data sets, (esp for table_a) the full query and the observed behaviour.

Comment: Hi All, its like this
IF(PARAMETER_VALUE='FALSE' AND aPARAMETER_NAME='SMS_SEND')
THEN INVALID_STAT ='Y'
ELSE 
' '

just need to transform this. im a newbie in SQL

Answer (score 0):

based upon your commentary, this will get you what you have asked for.

However, I doubt this is what you need. Please update your question as requested in the commentary above. If this does answer your question, please accept it as the answer and close the question.

I expect that the real requirement will be to wrap the following query in an outer join to a larger query (which you have not supplied) along with a coalesce to deal with the possible no rows scenario.

```sql
select 
  case
    when PARAMETER_VALUE = 'FALSE' THEN 'Y'
    else ''
  end as SMS_Send_Ind
from Table_A
where PARAMETER_Name = 'SMS_SEND'
;
```

If there is no record in the table with Parameter_name = 'SMS_SEND', then the query will return no rows. Otherwise it will a Y or a blank as determined by the number of records in Table_A with parameter_name = 'SMS_SEND'